# Gizmos not being drawn until GameObject selected

Tags: unity, debugging, scene

I have implemented Scene loading in my game and have three scenes: `Persistent`, `Main Menu` and `Game`

By default, the player is loaded into the `Persistent` scene, which immediately loads the `Main Menu`, and when the player clicks on Play, `Main Menu` is unloaded and `Game` is loaded.

Now, the two active scenes are `Persistent` and `Game`.

However, I have a script with `OnDrawGizmos` on a GameObject in the `Game` scene. It seems that by default gizmos only begin to be drawn when I click on that GameObject, sort of activating it, and everything works fine. This used to just work before because `Game` was my only scene and Unity automatically selected that first GameObject. Now, with multiple scenes, no GameObject is selected by default and my gizmos won't draw until I manually click on it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `OnDrawGizmos` and `OnDrawGizmosSelected` handle unselected/selected game objects. I'd suspect in your case it's not so much about selecting the *object* as selecting *something* in the *scene*. Unity might disable gizmos from scenes other than the one containing your last selection, either to reduce scene view clutter or improve performance in multi-scene editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this

> Selection.activeGameObject = {Whatever object you want selected}

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution solved it. But with this I can't build my project. What can I do for that? I saw that changing build setting from gradle to internal could solve this but I'm using unity 2020.3 and that option is not available here.

Comment: @Kavisha presumably you considered wrapping your use of the UnityEditor namespace in an `#if UNITY_EDITOR` preprocessor directive, so that it's not included in standalone builds?

Comment: @KavishaSamarasinghe Any scripts in a folder called "Editor" will not be included in the final build. Likewise, as @DMGregory says, you can wrap any code using editor extensions in a `#if UNITY_EDITOR` ... `#endif`. Any code between those directives will be cut out before building.