# Gizmos disappear after a scene transition

Tags: unity, debugging, scene

I have used OnDrawGizmos function to draw some cubes. If I run the project from that particular scene, the gizmos are visible. But after a scene transition they disappear. It appears again if I select the Gamobject that contains my script with the OnDrawGizmos function.

I tried adding the Selection.activeGameObject and it worked but I can't build my project because unity editor is being involved in my scipt. Adding a Editor folder and keeping my scipt there does not allow me to drag and drop the script to the hierachy, so that I can attach the relavant gameobject that should be active.

I also tried #if UNITY_EDITOR ... #endif, but after building the app, the app still did not show the gizmos on my phone.

Please can anyone let me know a way to stop gizmos from disappearing.

Comment: This looks very similar to [this previous Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/190072/39518).

Comment: Can you show us the final code you used with the UNITY_EDITOR directives and all? Also, you mention the gizmos did not show on your phone — gizmos are never displayed in the build running on your device, only ever in the editor, so if you want to draw something on your phone you will need a different strategy.

Comment: @DMGregory yes it is. I couldn't comment there without 50 reputations. Sorry for that. It is similar but I couldn't find the solution there. The mentioned solution didn't work for me. And thank you so much for letting me know that gizmos aren't ever displayed in the build. I was walking on a dead end. I'll try a different strategy. Thank you.

Comment: You should then be sure your question shows in detail how you tried implementing that solution. Otherwise we might just point you back at the same answer and say "this one worked for me" which does not help you. You need to show us the details so we can spot what's going wrong.